# Linux poclbm error

Tags: poclbm

I'm running on linux, just installed PyOpenCL, but when I run poclbm I get this error:

```
 03/01/2013 16:49:12, Ignored invalid server entry: username:password@host:port
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poclbm.py", line 84, in <module>
    import BFLMiner
  File "/home/myhome/btc/poclbm-master/BFLMiner.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ioutil import find_udev, find_serial_by_id, find_com_ports
  File "/home/myhome/btc/poclbm-master/ioutil.py", line 2, in <module>
    from serial.tools import list_ports
ImportError: No module named tools
```

I run it with the following command:
`python poclbm.py -d 0 username:password@host:port`

Is there something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also need to install `pyserial`. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14109679/204052) for details.

Comment: After installing `pyserial`:
`user@machine:~/btc/poclbm-master$ python poclbm.py -d 0 user.worker:pass@http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332
 04/01/2013 10:25:40, Ignored invalid server entry: user.worker:pass@http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332

At least one server is required` Do you know what that means?

Comment: Put `http://` in front of `user.worker` and it should work. The address you are using right now (`username:password@http://...`) is not a valid URL.